# Do not get the first, but the second match in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

For this string

```
Some AB, Author C., Names DEF. The title string. T journal name 2018;10:560-564
```

I would like to get just the authors. So I tried to split for `.` (dot and space).

But using the regex `/^(.*)(?:\.\s).*/` doesn't match for my expected `Some AB, Author C., Names DEF`, instead I do get also the title as my first match.

I don't understand why. Maybe someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

https://regex101.com/r/HLBmbf/1

Comment: Use lazy quantifier `^(.*?)\.\s`

Comment: An alternative regex with a lazy quantifier that would also capture that: `^(?:.*?,){2}[^,.]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will capture what you're looking for.

`^(.*)(?:\.\s.*\.\s).*`

Basically you were not capturing the last `\.\s` only, when you needed to not capture the last 2 instances of that.